# Average over groups and include previous groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df, a sample of which was created below). I want to group by group1 and group2 and take the average of the value. When taking the average, I want to include previous groups within group1.

```
df = data.frame(group1 = c('a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'), 
                group2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,2), 
                values = c(2,3,4,3, 9,3,2,5,6,3,0))
```

An example may best illustrate: the first and second rows belong to the same group and they average 2.5. The third and fourth group belong to the same group and they average 3.5. But because they also belong to group1 (a), I want the desired outcome to be 3, as shown below.

```
group1  group2  meanvalues
a          1    2.5
a          2    3
a          3    4.2
b          1    2.5
b          2    3.33
c          1    6
c          2    3
```

Below is my code, but they only take the average within each group

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
  summarize(meanvalues = mean(values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do the following:

```
df %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% summarise(values = sum(values), n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(meanvalues = cumsum(values) / cumsum(n)) %>% select(-values, -n)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   group1 [3]
#   group1 group2 meanvalues
#   <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 a           1       2.5 
# 2 a           2       3   
# 3 a           3       4.2 
# 4 b           1       2.5 
# 5 b           2       3.33
# 6 c           1       6   
# 7 c           2       3
```

What you want is a cumulative grouped mean. Now it doesn't seem to be possible in one step, so first I compute grouped sums and group lengths, and then and compute the cumulative grouped mean.